# iPad Modal View Dismiss Animation Issue

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ipad

When I present a modal view in iPad, the view comes up from the bottom. But when I dismiss it, it slides of the screen to the left. I'm in landscape mode and using UIModalPresentationStylePageSheet. How do I make the dismiss animation slide the view back down?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Did you solve it?

Comment: I solved it by adding the modal view at the window level

Comment: You might want to answer your own question and mark it as correct. (I"m having the same problem. Glad I came here.)

Answer (score 0):

See a different solution here: [Modal View Controller with keyboard on landscape iPad changes location when dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898353/modal-view-controller-with-keyboard-on-landscape-ipad-changes-location-when-dismi)