# resignFirstResponder not hiding keyboard on textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, keyboard

I have a view with a UITextField which should hide the keyboard when return is pressed.

My function is this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
 if ( textField == userPassword ) {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
 return YES;
}
```

Normally the keyboard should be hidden but it stays on the screen. resignFirstResponder is correctly called. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried returning NO? Returning YES may cause the text field to run some code which would make it first responder again.

Comment: Yes I did, it changed nothing. The focus however seems to be removed from the field, the (X) on the right side to clear the fields content is no longer shown after resignFirstResponder

Comment: I'm having the same problem on iPad

Comment: Same problem.  Ever figured it out?

Comment: not yet, I am still looking :(

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I see you have the iPad tag on this. Do you happen to be presenting a modal view using UIModalPresentationFormSheet? If so, it looks like this is a limitation of the FormSheet modal presentation (either Apple is doing it intentionally for some reason, or it is a bug). See these other questions for more details:

[Modal Dialog Does Not Dismiss Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/)

[Modal View Controller with keyboard on landscape iPad changes location when dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898353/)

Comment: thats exactly what is happening, thank you, I accepted your answer because it explains that this is some Apple behaviour/bug

Comment: Wow, it took me a while to find this answer and it works perfectly. I had no ide it was related to a UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

Comment: tony.stack's answer actually fixes the issue.

Comment: I solved this by executing `resignFirstResponder` in the main queue.. Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 33):

There is this helpful method which allows you to dismiss the keyboard when presenting the Modal Dialog:

```
 - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal { return NO; }
```

This will override the default behavior of the modal dialog set by Apple and allow you dismiss the keyboard. It is in the UIViewController Class.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: The behavior is intentional on Apples part. Read the docs for disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal. Thanks Tony, this helped a lot!

Comment: This solution is good. If you are looking for a fix, try it.  Worked for me.

Comment: Put it in the class that invokes the UITextView or Text Thingy for your Keyboard.

Comment: Use lower case r in return ;)

Comment: changed to lower case r in return! ty!

Comment: this is THE answer! The long awaited mystery solved.

Comment: I had to subclass UINavigationController and add this method in there.  This was because my Modal view controller Root was a NavigationController.

Comment: To be put in the class that is presented as a modal.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the Interface Builder, look if your UITextField has the delegated linked with your class.

**-Select your UITextField and in your Connections look if exits one connection in Outlets->delegate. If not, conect with you File's Owner Class.**

This need to be linked with your File's Owner Class. This delegate tell where to search for a method. If your are overriding a method, you need to tell where the object will search for that.

Comment: The responder is correctly called, its not a matter of the delegate. Thank you for trying :-)

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me after none of the above did. after calling resignFirstResponder i added a modal view & removed it.

```
    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    UIViewController *dummyController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *dummy = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1,1,1)];
    [dummyController setView:dummy];
    [self presentModalViewController:dummyController animated:NO];
    [dummyController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Keyboard animation is gone (as are my animations associated with it) but yeah, this is the only solution that works for me.

Answer (score 4):

To deal with the bug mentioned by Brandon, you can try closing and re-opening your modal view controller as long as you still have a reference to it.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:yourModalViewControllerReference animated:NO];
```

(where "self" should be the controller you used to originally open the modal view controller)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I realized that after connecting the delegate to the File's Owner in Interface Builder, I neglected to save in Interface Builder. Once I saved, I recompiled and the keyboard disappears correctly when hitting return.

Answer (score 3):

**xcode 4.5.1**

Simply click control then on the textfield drag and release on the **.h** file

(**control key+ drag**)

then in the pop up menu select

```
connection=acton;
name= any name;
type=id;
event=did end on exit;
arguments=sender;
```

then **click connect button**

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol?

Comment: If you implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol you can inadvertently cause this behavior if you do text validation. If your validation codes returns false from textFieldShouldEndEditing when the text is invalid, the field can't relinquish it's firstResponder status and the keyboard will remain on screen in the next view. More details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379205/uitextfields-keyboard-wont-dismiss-no-really/37082876#37082876

Answer (score 1):

I have read so many articles about this issue, where the onscreen keyboard refuses to hide when you call `resignFirstResponder`, but none of the suggestions worked for me.

I'm using XCode 5 (iOS 7) and have a iPhone screen containing a couple of controls which require the onscreen keyboard, but if the user clicks on the `UIButton`, then I want the keyboard to disappear.

[image]

I probably wasted one full day experimenting with `resignFirstResponder` and adding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` functions to return NO, but nothing worked.  Once the onscreen keyboard appeared, I could never get it to disappear again.

But then I had a small brainwave  (as I only have a small brain).

Now, when the user clicks on my `UIButton`, I simply *disable* the `UITextField` and `UITextView` controls.

```
- (IBAction)btnDate_Tapped:(id)sender {
    //  The user has clicked on the "Date" button.
    self.tbClientName.enabled = NO;
    self.tbComments.editable = NO;
```

And suddenly, the app finds it has no editable text fields needing an onscreen keyboard, and it neatly slides the keyboard out of sight.

(Relieved sigh.)

My `UIButton` actually makes a popup dialog appear.  When the user dismisses the popup, I re-enable these two controls, so if the user taps in one of them, the keyboard will appear again.

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
    //  The user has closed our popup dialog.
    //  We need to make our UITextField and UITextView editable again.
    self.tbClientName.enabled = YES;
    self.tbComments.editable = YES;
    ... etc...
}
```

Simple, isn't it !

And surprisingly, this workaround even works on `UIViewControllers` which appear in **Modal** style.

I hope this helps other XCode victims out there.

Comment: Please help Ive also been struggling with this for a full day now! I have done everything you've said is there anything else that could possible differ in your app that i can change in mine?

Comment: My UIButton is shown in the screenshot above (showing the date/time).  When the user clicks on this, I wanted the onscren keyboard to disappear, and a popup to appear, where they could select a date.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that it looks like focus has shifted, then I think what may be happening is that the keyboard is staying open for the next text input field.  If your return key is a "Next" key, then returning YES for textFieldShouldReturn: will make the next textField the first responder, and keep the keyboard visible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

1. Go to your user interface builder,
2. select `UITextField` and "Control-Drag" to "Detail View Controller-Detail" and release.
3. The window will pop-up. Then under "Outlets" select "Delegate".

That's it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in UIModalPresentationFormSheet just call

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have already given that answer almost a year earlier - FYI. :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0:

```
override var disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool {
    get{
        return false
    }
    set {
        self.disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == addressTextField {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```