# resignFirstResponder Don't work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, resignfirstresponder

I try to hide keyboard on iPad but I don't know why resignFirstResponder don't work.
But popToRoot has work well.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[descTF text]];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    return YES;
}
```

So Could you guide me what should I do please ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124828/resignfirstresponder-not-hiding-keyboard-on-textfieldshouldreturn

Comment: I try to put 
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
on my code under - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{...} but Keyboard still didn't hide.

Comment: in the link I post, the problem might be a bug from Apple.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this field inside a `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`? If so, it's a known issue that you can not dismiss the keyboard programmatically until the view controller gets dismissed.

**UPDATE**: according to [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/425914) from the Apple Developer Forums, a possible workaround for this is to present the sheet view control from inside a navigation controller subclass that implements the disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal method. So something like:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
CustomNavigationController *navController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
theNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:theNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Added possible workaround and link to Apple Developer Forums thread.

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on samvermette's answer, if it is inside a `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` you can now override the `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` method to get the behavior you desire.  Add the following method to your class and the `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` will respond to resignFirstResponder.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: +1 This should really be the selected answer (obviously the original selected answer was correct at one time). Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have occasion to send `-resignFirstResponder`.  What you should do is just send `-endEditing:YES` to the view  in question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` ? If you had implemented that then this, then it should work.

Comment: I already add <UITextFieldDelegate>. And also link delete @xib file. T^T But it still didn't hide.

Comment: `textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone` ?

Comment: errr Could you guide me what should I do for "textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone" ???

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies... this is the fourth place on the StackOverflow site where I'm posted this fix..)

I had huge problems with XCode 5 & iOS 7, trying to get the onscreen keyboard to hide.

Eventually, I found a very simple solution:  I just disabled the `UITextFields` in my form.  Magically, this was enough to make the onscreen keyboard slide away.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124828/resignfirstresponder-not-hiding-keyboard-on-textfieldshouldreturn/23221200#23221200)

Surprisingly, this even works on Modal `UIViewControllers`.  Yeah, it surprised me aswell !!