# How do I dismiss a Modal View Controller Form Sheet in Landscape on iPad containing a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have a Modal View Controller presented as a Form Sheet in Landscape on an iPad. When I dismiss the view, the view jumps to a different location, as in this thread:

A modal VC with a keyboard on landscape changes location when dismissed:
[Modal View Controller with keyboard on landscape iPad changes location when dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898353/modal-view-controller-with-keyboard-on-landscape-ipad-changes-location-when-dismi)

The response to that thread is to call resignFirstResponder, however, you are not allowed to dismiss keyboards when using a Form or Page Sheet:

[Modal Dialog Does Not Dismiss Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/modal-dialog-does-not-dismiss-keyboard)

Has any one else had this problem? Is there a way to either force the keyboard to be dismissed or force the view into a nice position when it's being animated away?

Cheers,
Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard will be removed only after the modal form is dismissed. Apple has the idea that if you are using modal form, then you'll need the keyboard for multiple fields therefore it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Thanks Guy - if this is the case then perhaps this should be closed & a bug raised with Apple in that a Modal VC needs it's keyboard dismissed before the window will animate out without glitches.

Comment: Right, however if you do, you probably won't be the first, Apple insists that this is the way to go.